# How I can convert time variable from sas data in R?

Tags: r, sas

I loaded sas data(.sas7bdat) into R and a 'time' variable was changed to a number.

For instance, in SAS:

```
"03FEB15:23:45:02"
```

This time value is shown in R as:

```
"1738626302"
```

How I can convert this value to the following time value:

```
03FEB15:23:45:02
```